# Plot rectangles using geom_rect with continous x-axis and discrete values in y-axis (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, yaxis

I am trying to plot rectangles in the x-axis for different classes in the y-axis. I want to do this with `geom_rect`, but I don't want to use `y_min` and `y_max` since I want these to be determined by the classes (i.e. factors) I have in my data.

I managed to get the plot I want changing the breaks and the tick labels manually, but I am sure there must be a better way to do this.

Small toy example:

```
data <- data.frame(x_start = c(0, 2, 4, 6),
                   x_end = c(1, 3, 5, 7),
                   y_start = c(0, 0, 2, 2),
                   y_end = c(1, 1, 3, 3),
                   info = c("x", "x", "y", "y"))
```

Original plot:

```
ggplot(data ,aes(xmin=x_start, xmax=x_end, ymin=y_start, ymax=y_end, fill=info)) + geom_rect()
```

[image]

Plot that I want:

```
ggplot(data ,aes(xmin=x_start, xmax=x_end, ymin=y_start, ymax=y_end, fill=info)) + geom_rect() +
        scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0.5,2.5), labels = c("x","y"))
```

[image]

Comment: If x and y are factors then the numerical value on the y-axis will depend on their factor representation. Appears you want the first two rows to have rectangles at (x=0-1, y=0.75-1.25) and the next two at (4-5, 1.75-2-25). Just set up a dataset like that and plot in the ordinary gg-way..

Comment: @IRTFM -- could you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: Jon Spring has given an answer. I could not tell how you thought the data was arranged. Were there supposed to be specific values for x and y? And were you hoping to see a fixed offset above and below those values for the bounds o the rectangle? Or did you have a range for x and y and wanted the y axis labels to be centered on each range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
y_lab <- data %>%
  distinct(y_end, y_start, info) %>%
  mutate(y_mid = (y_end + y_start)/2)

ggplot(data, aes(xmin=x_start, xmax=x_end, ymin=y_start, ymax=y_end, fill=info)) +
  geom_rect() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = y_lab$y_mid, labels = y_lab$info)
```

[image]

Or using `geom_tile`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = (x_start + x_end)/2, y = info, fill=info, width = 1)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

Comment: This code works, but it's pretty similar to what I was doing -- isn't there a way to simply use a categorical variable for y? perhaps there is another `geom_function` that I don't know that will work similar to rectangles but could plot categorical variables on the y-axis?

Comment: Edited with `geom_tile()` alternative. It is parameterized by its center x/y and its width/height, and works more automatically with discrete axes.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense -- I've accepted the answer!